# Auto scroll sheet to active row while using userform

Tags: excel, vba, scroll

Entering data via a userform.  After a few entries I can no longer see the active cell and I can't scroll the sheet while the userform is active.

I would like the sheet to auto-scroll to keep the active cell/row visible while I enter data on the userform.

I tried adding code found online but they all failed.

```vb
Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub


Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

Dim emptyRow As Long
If TextBox1.Value <> "" And TextBox2.Value <> "" Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RO-BOX DETAILS")
        emptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox2.Value = ""
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    End With
End If

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

1. I scan into textbox 1 and it moves the focus to textbox 2
2. I scan into textbox 2 and it adds the data to the next empty row - no
   clicking 'OK' required.
3. The focus returns to textbox 1.
4. Repeat

Now I want to keep the next empty row visible so I can see the entries go in on the fly. Basically to ensure they scanned correctly.
Right now, I close the userform every so often to scroll down and look manually.

Comment: Hi. Just select one cell on the next empty row. Try something like Cells(emptyRow+1, 1).select

Comment: Have a look at [`Window.ScrollIntoView` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.scrollintoview?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm356132)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Answer (score 0):

It won't quite achieve the autoscrolling you requested, but you could try calling the userform with it's ShowModal property set to "modeless".  That would at least allow the user to manually scroll the sheet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/showmodal-property

...there's no example to follow on that page, but it would go something like...

```
sub CallNormsUserForm()
    NormsUserForm.show vbModeless
end sub
```